I am making a room sized camera obscura but I want to capture a specific view not directly in front of the windows. Is there a way to do this?
To explain a bit further. I am trying to capture the train coming which you can only see if you turn a bit to the left looking at an oblique angle. I am wondering if there is a way to calculate where the hole needs to be to capture this specific view or if its possible to direct the light with a straw or potentially use a mirror to direct the view?
thanks,
Anna

How thick is the wall with the hole? As long as there is a straight line from the train, through the hole, and to the opposite wall, the train should appear.

I assume that you're covering the windows with some kind of light-tight membrane with a pinhole.
If so, then if you can normally see the desired scene when looking out the window to the left, then the rays from that scene will pass through the pinhole and hit the wall to the right of the window.  The projected scene will be distorted, since (assuming a rectangular room) the rays will be hitting the wall at a fairly oblique angle, as compared to the relatively perpendicular angle for rays from directly outside the window which then hit the far wall of the room.
This assumes (as was pointed out in the comments) that the window covering is negligible thickness, and therefore that the pinhole itself is of negligible depth compared to its width.  If depth and width of the hole are comparable, this will reduce the field of view of the pinhole, and rays from outside this field of view will not be able to pass through the pinhole.l
You could avoid all of these complications by placing a mirror directly outside the pinhole, so when you look straight out from the pinhole location, you see the desired scene.  This effectively creates a virtual object for the pinhole that is straight out from the window, and so it will create an image of this virtual object on the far wall like normal.

thank you so much for your answer. Yes i will cover the windows with black out film.


I am making a room sized camera obscura but I want to capture a specific view not directly in front of the windows. Is there a way to do this?

You could place two mirrors outside of the camera obscura, which mirrors are not exactly parallel, with the mirrors angled approximtely 45 degrees from the wall.
